# What's the relationship between Encoder and CatalystSerde

Tags: apache-spark

`Encoder` is used to `serialize/deserialize` an Java object to Spark SQL's internal Row. So, I think it is the SerDe framework,

But, I also see another object named `CatalystSerde`. I would ask what the relationship between `Encoder and CatalystSerde`. Following is the definition of `CatalystSerde`

```
object CatalystSerde {
  def deserialize[T : Encoder](child: LogicalPlan): DeserializeToObject = {
    val deserializer = UnresolvedDeserializer(encoderFor[T].deserializer)
    DeserializeToObject(deserializer, generateObjAttr[T], child)
  }

  def serialize[T : Encoder](child: LogicalPlan): SerializeFromObject = {
    SerializeFromObject(encoderFor[T].namedExpressions, child)
  }

  def generateObjAttr[T : Encoder]: Attribute = {
    val enc = encoderFor[T]
    val dataType = enc.deserializer.dataType
    val nullable = !enc.clsTag.runtimeClass.isPrimitive
    AttributeReference("obj", dataType, nullable)()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark uses encoders for serialization purpose where I heard about catalyst optimizer not serde but it works to optimize serialization in spark.

Below is important points when we are considering encoders and catalyst optimizer,

1. The encoder is primary concept in serialization and deserialization (SerDes) framework in Spark SQL. Encoders translate between JVM objects and Spark's internal binary format. Spark has built-in encoders which are very advanced. They generate bytecode to interact with off-heap data.
2. Catalyst serde includes, specialized in-memory data structures tuned for the type of operations required by Spark, improved code generation, and a specialized wire protocol.
   It's representation is substantially smaller than objects serialized using Java or even Kryo serializers.

Comment: Thanks @ajay-kharade for the great answer, but..mm, I am afraid that I still doens't get the point